# exception types in exception handling

Tags: dart

if error handling in dart in the catch block chain applies the supertype first and then the subtypes in subsequent catch blocks, then the catch blocks corresponding to the subtypes will never work. In visual studio code, a warning is displayed in these cases. I believe a static error should be generated.

```
class A implements Exception {}

class B extends A {}

void main() {
  try {
    var x = 1;
  } on A {
  } on B {
    // warning
  } on Exception {} // warning
}
```

1. Is it possible to configure the analyzer so that an error is generated instead of a warning?
2. Why isn't this done by default?
3. Is it possible to configure the analyzer, compiler so that block reordering is performed automatically by the dart fix command, for example?

I would like to get an error with the wrong catch order, as well as the possibility of its automatic correction.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to generate an error if some of the catch blocks will never be executed due to the fact that the base class can be in the first catch block, and the child class will already be in the second.

Requires setting in analysis_options.yaml file.

analyzer:
errors:
dead_code_catch_following_catch: error

But I have not yet found a way to automatically reorder catch blocks. If someone finds it would be great. In general, it would be possible at the level of the dart compiler to consider the possibility of introducing a mechanism in which the catch blocks of child classes would always be performed first before the catch blocks of parent classes.